# Azure Mobile Services - Authorization architecture design

Tags: angularjs, azure, azure-mobile-services, azure-web-app-service

I would like some design or architecture advice for the recommended way to implement `authorization` in my application. Its a angularjs front end that is using azure mobile services to store the data.

I have already gone through the process of getting the authentication to work with Microsoft (MS) accounts & other providers. What I am trying to figure out how is how to do authorization (not authentication) for the following scenarios:

1. I would like to authorize specific users as valid users of the my site before they have even signed-in. Essentially I would like to create an account and send it to them OR enter their MS username/email and allow them to access the site. I do not want to just allow anyone with a MS account to login.
2. The users created from case 1 ("admins") would then be able to invite or add other users through my application.

My current idea is to create a table of authorized users in azure mobile services that would contain the user id, and a bool to indicate admin access. I would use this table in my application to grant/deny some one access to the site. I would also disable the ability to add new users if they are not a admin. So my questions are:

1. Is this a reasonable approach or is there a built in way to do this?
2. Is there a better design pattern to accomplish what I'm trying to do?
3. How do I obtain the proper id for someones MS account ahead of time? (before they have even signed into my account)

Any good samples or examples would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am in exactly similar dilemma as I have an HTML5/JS single pager Application which is getting authenticated against Azure Mobile Services. But I also want just the AUTH users to call specific methods of my app.

A suggestion would be to check Azure B2C feature which is new offering from Microsoft that might solve your problem.

http://blogs.technet.com/b/ad/archive/2015/09/16/azure-ad-b2c-and-b2b-are-now-in-public-preview.aspx

Comment: I received a similar recommendation directly from Microsoft and it looks like it will be a good solution.